# Keep Lua tmpfile after execute

Tags: lua, temporary-files, tmp, tmpfs, luafilesystem

Uploades file represented as tmpfile() and will be removed then script exits.
How to hardlink this file to keep its content after removing tmpfile?

How to get name of file by its handle?

```
> a=io.tmpfile()
> print(a)
file (0x20c8790)
> lfs=require"lfs"
> lfs.link(a,"/tmp/aaaa")
stdin:1: bad argument #1 to 'link' (string expected, got FILE*)
stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'lfs.link'
    stdin:1: in main chunk
    [C]: in ?
```

This file is too big to copy it by byte to another.

Comment: Just use regular files. On windows I know there exists way to get name by handle. Also it possible get handle from FILE* (but there may some problem if you link with static MSCRT). But do you really need this instead of just create file by hand  and use it as tmp? This is my impl. https://github.com/moteus/lua-path/blob/master/lua/path.lua#L229

Comment: Use [os.tmpname()](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-os.tmpname) instead of io.tmpfile()

Comment: io.tmpfile() is inside library, so i wanted not to edit this

Answer (score 1):

io.tmpfile uses tmpfile of stdio.h, so it wont be possible to adjust this exported function.
you can use libraries such as [pl.path](https://stevedonovan.github.io/Penlight/api/libraries/pl.path.html#tmpname) to get full path of temp file.